# Reverse an OrderedSet in an Eclipse Modeling Framework Model via OCL

Tags: uml, eclipse-emf, modeling, ocl

I have a UML model (which is actually irrelevant as it could be any MOF model) with an ordered set I need to access from the last to the first element. I thus need to reverse it through OCL. I have seen there is the sortedBy method that needs an OCLExpression to use as sorting criterion but I can't get how to use it.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Acceleo (your comment is suggesting that you are), you have two options:

- use "myOrderedSet->reverse()" provided by the [Acceleo library](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Acceleo/Acceleo_Operations_Reference#reverse_.28.29_.28Only_on_ordered_collections.29) (that's not 100% pure OCL)
- use something like "myOrderedSet->iterate(elem: MyType| myOrderedSet.insertAt(0, elem))"

Edit: It's been a long time since I used iterate since I use reverse all the time, the correct for of the iterate is this: [link](https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/105625286543794908607/albums/5552047126204483729/5712582089426445570). And in case anyone had a doubt, here is the answer with reverse: [link](https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/105625286543794908607/albums/5552047126204483729/5712578132905610898)

Regards,

Stephane Begaudeau

Comment: iterate does not seem to be an OCL valid method for an OrderedSet.

Comment: Well since it seems that you are really using Acceleo so "->reverse()" is the easiest way to go and as my link to the Acceleo documentation shows it, it is implemented on OrderedSet and Sequence: [link](https://plus.google.com/photos/105625286543794908607/albums/5552047126204483729/5712578132905610898). Just be sure that you have an OrderedSet and not a Set that does not have the reverse operation.

Comment: I have edited my answer with a correction on the declaration of iterate and a screenshot of both solutions tested in Acceleo.

Comment: thank you very much Stephane. I am actually trying to get the fragments contained in an Interaction in the exact order they are contained in the model but reversed. To this end I am doing interaction.fragment->asOrderedSet() and it actually returns the ordered set of fragments. However it marks as error both interaction.fragment->asOrderedSet()->reverse() and iterate but as I get to my Office I will check the installed ACCELEO version. Thank you again for your kind help